# Cat magic - end of input

Tags: linux, shell

When "cat > xx.txt << EOF" is entered on the command line, further input from cmdline goes to file xx.txt until EOF is written. EOF is not a sacred word here, if instead the command was cat > xx.txt << BBB, then cmdline input   goes to xx.txt until BBB is written. I don't know whats the rationale behind ( << end_of_input_sequence)this. Cat man page does not explain much.
I have only seen this in scripts etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a feature of the shell, not `cat` - that's why you won't find it in the `cat` manual.

It's known as a "Here document" - see this page of the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) for some documentation.

Answer (score 7):

This is called a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document). I believe it first appeared in shells, but some programming languages such as Perl, Ruby, and PHP also implement this style.

Answer (score 4):

This syntax is called [Here Document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections) (scroll a bit to find it).

It's not specific to any command, not cat anymore than any other command ; and it can be find in the man of the shell ; for instance, `man bash` :

> 3.6.6 Here Documents
>
> This type of redirection instructs the
>   shell to read input from the current
>   source until a line containing only
>   word (with no trailing blanks) is
>   seen. All of the lines read up to that
>   point are then used as the standard
>   input for a command.

*(Not a full quote -- there is more to read in the man)*

*BTW, It's a syntax that has been re-used in some programming languages, like PHP ;-)*